# Server 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS live CD upgrade - No new release found

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, server, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a server with 12.04.05 LTS to 16.04.2 LTS via 14.04.05 LTS.

I have created a USB pen drive from the 14.04 ISO using startup disk creator and can successfully boot from it.

I have added an entry in the fstab file for the pen drive:
LABEL=Ubuntu-Server\04014.04.05\040LTS\040amd64 /media/cdrom auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0

This mounts correctly!

I then added the CDrom to the apt resource list:
sudo apt-cdrom add

It add 3 sources entries but completes with some warnings about skipping some packages (unsure if these are important)

When attempting the upgrade with
do-release-upgrade

I get:

No new release found

The pen drive containing the ISO is correctly mounted.

Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the full iso name? Also you mounted a directory not a cd iso image.